# jQuery datepicker - cannot select a date

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have created a date input field and want to edit it. For that I made the following script:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            $( "#leverdatum_ch").datepicker( {
                minDate: 1,
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var day = date.getDay();
                    return [(day != 0), ''];
                },            
            } );
        } );
</script>
```

This ensures that all days before the current date are disabbled and Sunday is not available. That works as expected. Only if I want to select a date is this not possible. a red bar will appear around the input field. I added this script in the `functions.php` of a wordpress website. the whole function in functions.php:

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'bbloomer_add_custom_checkout_field' );

function bbloomer_add_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) { 
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   woocommerce_form_field( 'leverdatum_ch', array(        
      'type' => 'date',        
      'class' => array( 'form-row-wide checkout-date-picker' ),        
      'label' => 'Leverdatum',        
      'placeholder' => '',        
      'required' => true,             
   ), $checkout->get_value( 'leverdatum_ch' ) ); ?>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            $( "#leverdatum_ch").datepicker( {
                minDate: 1,
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var day = date.getDay();
                    return [(day != 0), ''];
                },            
            } );
        } );
    </script><?php
}
```

the result if I pressed on a date:
[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yeah, sorry not thought of! but do you have any idea how i change the format?

browser console error:
The specified value "18/04/2020" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Answer (score 0):

Use format parameter in `datepicker();` and also make sure you installed `jquery.moment` file before `jquery.selectpicker.js`. I hope that resolves your issue, let me know if still don't work.